# Converting an std::array of std::bytes to a numeric value

Tags: c++

I wonder what a safe way to convert a compact subarray of `std::bytes` to a numeric value is. I guess this code:

```cpp
std::array<std::byte, 12> ar = { /* some bytes */ };
uint32_t value = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ar[4]);
```

is rather error-prone, for example because it depends on how the compiler aligns the values in the array. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so something like `std::memcpy(&result, &ar[4], sizeof(uint32_t))`, where `result` is a `uint32_t` would work fine and give the desired result?

Comment: @dawmd be aware of [endianess](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) of your system, too. if you have little endian and the 4 bytes from the array are e.g. 0x12345678 then your uint32 will hold 0x78563412.

Comment: [Oh the wonders of the technology](https://godbolt.org/z/ffdhzhe8h). Not all compilers are that capable though.

Comment: Assuming that the byte array if for network transfer or binary file data, you probably want to do something like `value = ar[0] + (ar[1] << 8) + (ar[2] << 16) + (ar[3] << 24)` in a utility function. That way, you decide if data is stored in big or little endian and the same code would works in both case.

Comment: @Phil1970 it is. This approach definitely works, but I wanted to come up with something more generic :D

Answer (score 1):

A reliable approach is to use [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to copy the target bytes over a `uint32_t` object. `memcpy` is required to safely accomplish this for every version of C++. This pattern is common enough that compilers can usually optimize out the copy.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
T read_int_from_bytes(const std::array<std::byte, N> & data, std::size_t index)
{
    if(index + sizeof(T) > N) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("read_int index out of bounds");
    }

    // Integer to copy the bytes to
    T result;

    // Copy the bytes
    std::memcpy(&result, &(data[index]), sizeof(result));

    return result;
}
```

Here is an example. This test creates an array of bytes with values `{ 0x00, 0x10, ..., 0xB0 }` and reads a `uint32_t` starting at the 4th byte.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::byte, 12> data{};
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        data[i] = static_cast<std::byte>(0x10 * i);
    }

    std::cout << "Ox" << std::hex << read_int_from_bytes<std::uint32_t>(data, 4);
}
```

The test produces `Ox70605040` when [I try it here](https://godbolt.org/z/5fzKzd18d). You can also notice from the assembly that the entire function call is optimized out and the result is precalculated, clearly showing that the compiler was able to reason through the `memcpy` and remove it entirely.

Beware the the results are unspecified, it depends on the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the target platform. That is, whether the first byte is the most significant or the least significant. For many applications this doesn't matter, but if it does C++20 introduced [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) which you can use to check the system's Endianness.